# Using BIM 360 Field API (legacy) to get checklist location

Tags: autodesk-bim360

Title is a good summary.

The /api/get_checklists POST is deprecated and returns back empty data. So I use the GET /fieldapi/checklists/v1/ to get the list of checklist items, and then I used the id in the GET /fieldapi/checklists/v1/:id to get the 'complete details.' Unfortunately the JSON data does not include the location/area (I have verified this by querying the data, then changing the location, querying it again, and comparing the results). Looking for a way to get this information.

Side note: Not a fan of including the ticket in the URL param. The GET does support including the ticket in the body though... (not a very good RESTFUL design though).

Using postman to query the information.

Some sample outputs (I scrubbed most of the values):

```
{
    "id": "",
    "project_id": "",
    "created_at": "",
    "updated_at": "",
    "created_by": "",
    "status": "Open",
    "company": {},
    "description": "",
    "source": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "type": "Equipment"
        }
    ],
    "identifier": "",
    "template": {
        "id": "",
        "name": ""
    },
    "checklist_type": "",
    "name": "",
    "priority": "",
    "signatures": [],
    "attachments": [],
    "custom_field_values": [
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",
            "value": "",
            "display_type": "",
            "possible_values": [
                "",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "",
            "name": "",
            "value": "",
            "display_type": "",
            "possible_values": [
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                ""
            ]
        }
    ],
    "comments": [],
    "sections": [
    ]
}
```

Comment: it looks it is true this property is missing. Please bear  with me checking with engineer team.

Comment: Update - we found that by querying /api/get_checklist_headers we can get the area_id property.

Comment: We logged a wish as mentioned in the answer below. Thank you for telling us you found the area_id of /api/get_checklist_headers. In addition, a kindly reminding: you have also the option to post questions of classic Field 360 at https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/bd-p/115, where more gurus of Field API are active there.

Answer (score 0):

our engineer team confirmed it is true the location isn’t included in fieldapi/checklists/v1:id.  And the example in API document result doesn’t show it returns location.  Sorry if this a bad news to you. I logged a wish CS-35616 to ask for exposing location with fieldapi/checklists/v1:id.

As to *The /api/get_checklists POST is deprecated and returns back empty data.* , you might need to specify ‘checklist_ids’ and ‘forced_checklist_ids’in the call. While by api/get_checklist_headers, get the ids ( completed_checklist_id) as the input.